# Common Progress bar in every activity Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have modify the solution. I am able to get the progress bar but the progress bar never gets hide

Here is class to create a progress bar with relative layout

```
public class ProgressBarHandler {
    private ProgressBar mProgressBar;
    private Context mContext;
    private View _baseView;
    private View _hideView;
    public ProgressBarHandler(Context context,View baseView, View hideView) {
        mContext = context;
        _baseView = baseView;
        _hideView = hideView;

        ViewGroup layout = (ViewGroup) _baseView;//((Activity) context).findViewById(android.R.id.content).getRootView();

        mProgressBar = new ProgressBar(context, null, android.R.attr.progressBarStyleLarge);
        mProgressBar.setIndeterminate(true);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

        RelativeLayout rl = new RelativeLayout(context);

        rl.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        rl.addView(mProgressBar);

        layout.addView(rl, params);

        hide();
    }

    public void show() {
        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        _hideView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

    public void hide() {
        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        _hideView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

This is my xml file

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/profile_activity">


<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/layout_to_hide"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@android:color/transparent"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@mipmap/wallpaper"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <com.deerwalk.androidcommon.RoundedImageView
                    android:id="@+id/profile_image"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    app:civ_border_color="#EEEEEE"
                    app:civ_border_width="4dp"
                    app:civ_shadow="true"
                    app:civ_shadow_radius="10"
                    app:civ_shadow_color="#8BC34A"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="false"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_margin="20dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/avatar" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/profile_image"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:id="@+id/txt_name"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:text=""
                        android:textColor="@color/white" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:id="@+id/txt_dob"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:text=""
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:textColor="@color/white" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>



        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">


</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Here is the activity class which call the progress bar

```
public class ProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    FrameLayout profile_root_layout;
    CoordinatorLayout layot_to_hide;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);
        profile_root_layout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.profile_activity);
        layot_to_hide = (CoordinatorLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_to_hide);
         new userProfileTask().execute();
    }




    public class userProfileTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            new ProgressBarHandler(getBaseContext(),profile_root_layout,layot_to_hide).show();
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean aBoolean) {

            new ProgressBarHandler(getBaseContext(),profile_root_layout,layot_to_hide).hide();
        }
    }

}
```

The progress bar never gets hides.Where I am doing mistake.

Comment: Every activity have its own layout. so you cann't have common progress bar for all activities.

Comment: yes I know every activity has its own layout . I think we can use the Layout inflate

Comment: instead why dont you create a dialog and call in each activity where you want to show progress dialog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a separate class then make a static method with the parameter on it the parameter contain Activity ... call this method on ur activity and pass the Activity name in it

Comment: can you pleases show a sample. I will be so helpful ... I am trying from 1 days

Comment: public class Config {

    public static void setProgressBar(Activity activity){
        progress=new ProgressDialog(activity);
        progress.setMessage("Downloading Music");
        progress.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        progress.setIndeterminate(true);
        progress.setProgress(0);
        progress.show();

    }

Comment: in your activities class you simply call Config. setProgressBar(YourActivityName);

Comment: how can i achieve this by progress bar

Comment: above you can see i made the separate Config class,and inside it i made the static method and call this method in ur activity classes

Comment: its working fine thanks but i need with progress bar . can you show me with progress bar.. Please

Answer (score 1):

Its very simple, you can do in multiple ways. 
1) You can define base activity and write your code for progress dialog and extends all activity from BaseActivity used Progressdialog.
2) You can have custom separate class and used in all activities.
etc

Here is good example you can modify your code like this example. 
[ProgressHud](https://github.com/anupamdhanuka/AndroidProgressHUD)

Or use this too.

Comment: I need with the progress bar

Comment: yes you can make progress bar too, its just give idea to show common  progress bar, you can modify progressHud to your requirement as you need progress bar.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest create a dialog and call in your activity class like this

```
dialog = new Dialog(getActivity(), android.R.style.Theme_Black);
    View views = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.activity_dialog, null);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.color.feed_item_bg);
    dialog.setContentView(views);
    dialog.show();
```

and in your async task onPostExecute dismiss dialog

```
dialog.dismiss();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void getProgress(Activity activity,FrameLayout relativeLayout){
final ProgressBar pb;
int progressStatus = 0;
final Handler handler = new Handler();
pb = new ProgressBar(activity, null, android.R.attr.progressBarStyleHorizontal);
LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(550,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
pb.setLayoutParams(lp);
LayoutParams params = (LayoutParams) pb.getLayoutParams();
pb.setLayoutParams(params);
pb.getProgressDrawable().setColorFilter(Color.BLUE, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
relativeLayout.addView(pb);
new Thread(new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
int progressStatus = 0;
while(progressStatus < 100){
progressStatus +=1;
try{
Thread.sleep(20);
}catch(InterruptedException e){
e.printStackTrace();
}
final int finalProgressStatus = progressStatus;
handler.post(new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
pb.setProgress(finalProgressStatus);
}
});
}
}
}).start(); // Start the operation
}
```

Comment: add this in ur config class and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a parent Activity. This activity class extends AppCompatActivity . Other Activities will extend this Activity. For example the name of this activity is AbstractActivty.

```
public class  AbstractActivty extends AppCompatActivity{

      AlertDialog alertDialogProgressBar;

      public void showLoadingProgressBar(String message, boolean cancalable) {
        if (isActivityPaused)
            return;

          AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
          View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.alert_dialog_progressbar_layout,null);
          TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.idTextViewMessage);
          tv.setText(message);
          adb.setView(view);
          alertDialogProgressBar = adb.create();
          alertDialogProgressBar.setCancelable(cancalable);
          alertDialogProgressBar.show();
}

 public void closeProgressBar() {
        if (alertDialogProgressBar == null) {
            return;
        }
        alertDialogProgressBar.hide();
    }

}
```

This class have a method which could be called by any other activity that extends
AbstractActivty

```
class MainActivty extends AbstractActivty{
   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // when require to show progressbar
        showLoadingProgressBar("Loading....",true)

        // when required to hide call
        closeProgressBar();

 }

}
```

Note in Alert Dialog we have used a custom layout 
   "alert_dialog_progressbar_layout.xml"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="@dimen/text_padding_l">


    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guidelineVertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".3"
        />


    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guidelineVertical"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/idTextViewMessage"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Loading...."
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/guidelineVertical"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Hope this will be of help . Thank you.