# create a common progress dialog to use in various activities

Tags: android

i have added a dependency of progress dialog from GitHub.. i am trying to create a common activity containing the progress dialog....

```
public class CustomProgressDialog extends AppCompatActivity {

AnimatedCircleLoadingView animatedCircleLoadingView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_custom_progress_dialog);
    animatedCircleLoadingView = (AnimatedCircleLoadingView) findViewById(R.id.circle_loading_view);
    ShowProgressDialog();
    stopWithSuccess();
    stopWithFailure();
}

public void ShowProgressDialog(){
    animatedCircleLoadingView.startDeterminate();
}

public void stopWithSuccess(){
    animatedCircleLoadingView.stopOk();
}

public void stopWithFailure(){
    animatedCircleLoadingView.stopFailure();
}
}
```

the code i used in other activity is...

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

CustomProgressDialog customProgressDialog;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    customProgressDialog = new CustomProgressDialog();
    DialogMethod();
   }


   public void DialogMethod(){
      customProgressDialog.ShowProgressDialog();
 }
}
```

i am getting the error as......

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.github.jlmd.animatedcircleloadingview.AnimatedCircleLoadingView.startDeterminate()' on a null object reference
```

What am i doing wrong...please help..

Comment: you need to remove all these ShowProgressDialog();
    stopWithSuccess();
    stopWithFailure(); methods from onCreate and use it explicitly when it needed

Comment: its still giving the same error

Comment: but y ur calling then in Dailog on create directly.

Comment: actually i was trying some hit and trial..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Common Progress bar in every activity Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36052732/common-progress-bar-in-every-activity-android)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't call it like this because AnimatedCircleLoadingView is not initialize yet. Do it something like below

```
 public static void showLoading(Context context) {
    builder = new Dialog(context);
    builder.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    builder.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(
            new ColorDrawable(Color.WHITE));
    builder.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
    builder.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {
            //nothing;
        }
    });
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View dialog_view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_mermaids_loading, null);
    PulsatorLayout p = (PulsatorLayout) dialog_view.findViewById(R.id.pulsator);
    builder.addContentView(dialog_view, new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

    builder.getWindow().setLayout(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    if (!((AppCompatActivity) context).isFinishing()) {
        builder.show();
        p.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: in the mainactivity?

Comment: You can use this in your common utilities class or in the base activity class. Or wherever you want

Comment: yes indeed... i was trying to call an activity from an activity...i just changed that to DialogFragment and it worked like a charm...

Comment: if my answer helps you in the right direction. Please consider it as accepting answer

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure why you would want a separate activity for the progress dialog. It sounds like unnecessary work, but I'll let you be the judge of that.

Personally I'm using the following method

```
private ProgressDialog setupProgressDialog(Context context) {
    ProgressDialog progress = new ProgressDialog(context);
    progress.setTitle(context.getString(R.string.label_progress_title));
    progress.setMessage(context.getString(R.string.label_progress_payment));
    progress.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
    progress.setCancelable(false);

    return progress;
}
```

This I can initialise and show using;

```
mProgressDialog = setupProgressDialog(mContext);
mProgressDialog.show();
```

and when my code has loaded I use;

```
if (mProgressDialog.isShowing()) {
    mProgressDialog.dismiss();
}
```

Now in regards to debugging your code, there is no need for executing all of your methods within your onCreate. Those are best use separately as you are already doing in your MainActivity.

You can read further about the ProgressDialog here;
[ProgressDialog - Android Developer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html)